# Simple cross-rate table question

Tags: arbitrage, currency, cross-currency-basis

I am trying to self-study and came across this question, I am not sure how to answer this.

I think I should transform all of the product's quoted prices to USD then compare them, is that correct?

> The table below shows retail prices of a single product in three countries. Use the
> cross-rate table and state which country’s currency is relatively (i) under-valued, and (ii) over-valued.

[image]

Comment: You are on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the idea of the [Big Mac Index](https://www.economist.com/big-mac-index). You have one product, and would like to figure out what the “fair” exchange rate is based on the theory (application) of [purchasing-power parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_purchasing_power_parity) (PPP). The link to the economist above shows a computation for the relative over- / under- valuation:

```
A Big Mac costs £3.49 in Britain and US$5.65 in the United States. The implied exchange rate is 0.62. The difference between this and the actual exchange rate, 0.73, suggests the British pound is 15.9% undervalued.
```

You can look [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/a/67940/54838) to get an idea how inflation impacts exchange rates.